# Java Spring Boot issue 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar is missing. @ line 57, column 21

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

What I want to achieve:
I am creating jar from IntelliJ using the edit configurations options. I created two configurations one for clean and the other one for install.

CLEAN Command:

```
clean -U
```

INSTALL Command:

```
install
```

Whenever I use clean and press the run button I get this error every time:

```
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 141, column 21
'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar is missing. @ line 57, column 21
The build could not read 1 project
```

What I have done up till now:

1. Reimported Maven
2. Deleted m2 repository
3. Removed the dependencies producing the error
4. Invalidate caches and restart

But there is no change in the error.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hrsg</groupId>
    <artifactId>EngagementSurvey</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EngagementSurvey</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.14.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-appstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.133</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error:

> [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
> 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be
> unique: com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar -> duplicate declaration of
> version (?) @ line 141, column 21

You have a duplicate dependency `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path` at line 141 which you must remove.

> dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar is missing. @ line 57, column 21

At line 57, you are using `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator` but you don't provide the version for it, and it not found in the parent spring boot.

The pom.xml you provide does not contains this line, which tell me you are providing the wrong pom.

If you don't have these dependencies, then it is most likely that they come from the parent:

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

However I don't think spring would release a pom with these mistake. You could try to use 2.4.5 instead.

Comment: I have removed com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path and org.hibernate:hibernate-validator from pom.xml but still I get this error. Also, I have tried using 2.4.5 version of spring boot but this makes no difference and I am getting the same error.

Comment: I tested your pom.xml in mvn: it works - even if I had to create a main for spring boot plugin. Either you have a problem with your setup in IntelliJ, either your problem is most likely you are not using your setup on the pom you provided in the question.